# JQuery Tab Events Triggers

Tags: php, jquery

I want to see tab No. 2 when "IF Condition" will meet the requirements. Here is my code. Please advice me how can I do this.

Thanks
Shahid

```
<?php
//Authorization / Security
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>

  <link type="text/css" href="../javascript/jquery/themes/ui-lightness/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.tabs.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
  alert('main');
  $("#container").tabs({
   ajaxOptions: {
    error: function(xhr, status, index, anchor) {
     $(anchor.hash).html("Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. If this wouldn't be a demo.");
    }
   }
  });
 });
  </script>
  <?php

 if($_GET['action'] == "add")
{
////////////////// Trigger Tab No. 2 ////////////////
/////////////////        and         ///////////////
//////////////// change url of Tab 3 ///////////////
}

?>
  </head>

  <body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><?php include("../includes/headerone.php");?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="15%"><?php include("../includes/leftbar.php");?></td>
            <td width="83%" ><div id="container">
                <ul class="tabs-nav">
                <li><a href="add.php"><span>Add</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="edit.php"><span>Edit</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="view.php"><span>View</span></a></li>
              </ul>
              </div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><?php include("../includes/footer.php");?></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try your script tag like this, it adds javascript to do what you want by echoing it into the self calling anonymous function if the php condition is met

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        alert('main');
        $("#container").tabs({
            ajaxOptions: {
            error: function(xhr, status, index, anchor) {
                $(anchor.hash).html("Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. If this wouldn't be a demo.");
            }
        }
    });
    <?php
        if($_GET['action'] == "add"){
            echo "$('.tabs-nav li a:eq(1)').trigger('click');";
            echo "$('.tabs-nav li a:eq(2)').attr('href', 'newurl');";
        }
    ?>
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy for your answer. but unfortunately its not working. I've tried your code but by default its 1st tab loaded. It doesn't go to tab2 when php if condition true. Please advice if I am wrong.

Comment: My bad, my selector was clicking on the <li> instead of the <a> element in the tab.  I fixed the example above and it works.